# How to load scripts required by asset-bundle unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I'm working on a unity project in which game scene get downloaded and run at run-time. I make it work by making asset-bundle of scene and load it but problem i'm facing is scripts required by scene are not included in asset-bundle. I just got stuck here can anyone please help me that, **how i can download/load required scripts** or **how i can include them in asset-bundle.**  so that i can load them at run-time also.

Sorry for bad English.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can add any type of asset you want in an asset-bundle.</s>
Script (.cs file) won't be able to be included in an asset-bundle.

The way you can add all <s>scripts</s>/materials/.. you needs, depends on what is included in your scene, is to store them all in a folder. Then you can assign the whole folder to a `AssetBundle tag` as should your scene be.

[image: Example]

Your scene the client needs to download has to be in the **same asset-bundle tag**.

**Note :** if you can't store them all in the same folder, just assign their asset-bundle tag manually for each asset (or subfolder) you want to add to the bundle.

Now you can run a method to create the bundle for you, as the following :

```cs
[MenuItem("Bundles/Create all bundles")]
static void BuildAllAssetBundles()
{
    BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "AssetBundleLocation"), BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows);
}
```

[There](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Workflow.html) is more information about **How to build an asset-bundle**.

Now all files required should be store in the asset-bundle file, **'Edit' except script files**. Take a look at [UnityEngine.AssetBundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.html) class to load and unload bundles/assets.

---

**Edit**

What will actually work to include your script file within an asset-bundle is to write your code in a **TextAsset** file (.txt).

Those files will give you a string once loaded from the asset-bundle.

```cs
AssetBundle ab = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "StreamingAssets/exampleassetbundle")); // Your asset-bundle path
TextAsset textAsset = ab.LoadAsset<TextAsset>(ab.GetAllAssetNames()[0]); // In my example I only have 1 file in the asset-bundle, the TextAsset
string flatCode = textAsset.text;
```

Now the thing is, you have to compile the flat string code to an actual C# class.
This is called **Runtime compilation**.

There is many tutorials about how to do it, [as this stackexchange post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130268/how-do-i-compile-a-c-script-at-runtime-and-attach-it-as-a-component-to-a-game-o).

It's a bit tricky, but will do what you want.

**Note :** IOS and Android may not let you compile code at runtime, so depends on your target platform, you will have to investigate further.

Comment: I'm getting the warning "Script assets cannot be included in AssetBundles: "Assets/Scripts/ButtonController.cs", attaching image also please check it. [link](https://ibb.co/5KstpKd)

Comment: That is true. After more investigation, any asset can go in an asset-bundle but .cs file (including MonoBehaviour). Will edit my post to give you how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to include programming in your asset bundles is to first compile your code into a dll and reference that dll from your assets. Then add the assets and the dll to the bundle and export it.